# Overall Big-O complexity of a while loop, with inner step that increases with every loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am beginning to learn complexity analysis and I can't figure out the overall Big-O complexity of this part of the algorithm, how should this be calculated?

```
Code Fragment               Time Complexity
1 -  C = 0                  O(1)
2 -  while C <= L           O(L)
3 -      f(C += 1)          O(???)
```

Step 3 in fact takes more steps, but can be summarized as a function f that takes C steps to execute.

My problem is that C is increased with every iteration, so any help or direction on that would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, the time complexity is `O(L * L)`. Because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .. + L = L * (L - 1) / 2.

Comment: Just one thing: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + L = L* (L **+** 1) / 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's plug a few numbers there and see what happens.

- For L=0, step 3 runs once with 0 steps;
- For L=1, step 3 runs twice with 0, and then 1 steps;
- For L=2, step 3 runs 3 times with 0, 1, and 2 steps;
- For L=3, step 3 runs 4 times with 0, 1, 2, and 3 steps;
  [...]
- For L=C, step 3 runs n times with 0, 1, ..., and C=L steps.

Let's say "zero steps" is constant time and change it to 1. So there are two ways to answer this:

- Your function runs 1+1+2+3+..+L steps. That's 1 + a series of L elements that sums to `1 + L * (L + 1) / 2`, so it's O(L<sup>2</sup>);
- It runs L times a function that can be bounded to O(L), so it's O(L<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Your explanation left me with a doubt, if Step 3 was wrapped in a loop executed in P steps, `P * f(C += 1)` , the overall complexity would be `O(PL^2)` right?? And thanks for the detailed explanation, it was very helpful!

Comment: That depends. If P changes with the size of the input, then yes. Otherwise it is a constant and does not change the Big-O.

Answer (score 1):

If `f(C)` takes `C` steps and `C` increases in every iteration up to the value `L` then the algorithm is `O(L^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If function f() *DOESN'T* change C ... then the overall complexity of the three lines you showed is O(N): The time will increase linearly as the size of `L - C` grows.  Neither line 1 nor line 3 contribute: they are both essentially "constant".

If function f() *DOES* change C (e.g. using a global variable), then BOTH lines 2 and 3 contribute, and cjungel's and giusti's answers are correct `O(L^2)`.

Here is a great article:

https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/how-to-calculate-big-o.html

Comment: `f()` is not really a function, just the body of the `for` loop that OP condensed into a function call for the sake of the question. And it must change the value of C, otherwise there's no algorithm to analyze! (Step 2 would turn into an infinite loop)